# MongoDB/NodeJS: Max connections / DB creation per variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loops, database-connection

I'd need your help with the max number of connection allowed with mongodb. I'm getting this error:

> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: null == 'MongoError: write EPIPE'

At first glance I thought of following this [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852689/mongoerror-write-epipe-in-parse-server-installation#38912160) and increase the max connection variable in the conf. file. 
But then I thought, it's silly, I don't really need these many connections, I should be able to limit the number to not overload my server and I actually found another [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439639/mongodb-max-connections) that goes in that direction.

So I went on in trying to figure out how can I create a new DB per instance of a variable, since it's what I'm trying to achieve and [found this in the NodeJS driver doc. for MongoDB](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html).

My code basically loop through 2 different Arrays. First: `ccxt.exchanges` (around 30 items) and then `pairs` (4 items) and I create a new connection each iteration of both of the arrays... Not sure if I'm clear but here's the code:

```
var _ = require("lodash");
var ccxt = require("ccxt");
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient,
  assert = require("assert");

let pairs = ["ETH/EUR", "BTC/EUR", "LTC/EUR", "BCH/EUR"];
let delay = 1200;

// NOTE: Server initiation:

setInterval(function() {
  ccxt.exchanges.forEach(r => {
    let exchange = new ccxt[r]();
    if (exchange.hasFetchOrderBook) {
      pairs.forEach(p => {
        exchange
          .fetchOrderBook(p)
          .then(async order => {
            if (_.isObject(order) && order.bids[0][1]) {
              let now = Math.floor(new Date());
              order.mkt = r;
              order.pair = p;
              let mkmodel = r.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + r.slice(1) + "order";
              var url = `mongodb://localhost:27017/${"order" + p.slice(0, 3)}`;
              MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
                assert.equal(null, err);
                var collection = db.collection(mkmodel);
                collection.insert(order, function(err, result) {});
                db.close();
              });
              let compOrder = {
                mkt: order.mkt,
                pair: order.pair,
                aprice: order.asks[0][0],
                avol: order.asks[0][1],
                bprice: order.bids[0][0],
                bvol: order.bids[0][1],
                sn: order.timestamp,
                ping: now - order.timestamp,
                fees: exchange.fees
              };
              var irl = `mongodb://localhost:27017/${"comp" + p.slice(0, 3)}`;
              MongoClient.connect(irl, function(err, db) {
                assert.equal(null, err);
                var collection = db.collection(mkmodel);
                collection.insert(compOrder, function(err, result) {});
                db.close();
              });
              console.log(compOrder);
              await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
            } else {
            }
          })
          .catch(e => {});
      });
    }
  });
}, 2000);
```

To simplify my code, it goes something like this:

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 30];
let array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

array1.forEach(i => { 
  array2.forEach(p => {
    new mongoConnection1 ==> Creates DB from Array2 (for instance: db = 1 on first iteration)
                             Each Array1 item creates a Collection
      db.close();
    someObjectManipulation
    new mongoConnection2 ==> Create different DB from Array2 as well
                             Each Array1 item creates a Collection as well
      db.close();
  })
})
```

Now since my code is asynchronous (and I'd rather keep it this way) the number of connections is too high and I get the error. 
I would like to do something like that:

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 30];
let array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
new mongoConnection

array1.forEach(i => { 
  array2.forEach(p => {
    Create DB from Array2 (for instance: db = 1 on first iteration)
          Each Array1 item creates a Collection
    someObjectManipulation
    Create different DB from Array2 as well
          Each Array1 item creates a Collection as well
  })
})

db.close();
```

in order to limit the number of connections to 1... But I'm not sure if it's possible at all? If it were, I guess that I would have to use `new Db(databaseName, topology, options)`([as presented in the Node driver docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html)) somewhere in my loops but I'm not sure how to do that...

I hope my question is clear enough otherwise please let me know in the comments and I'll try to clarify as much as needed! Thanks in advance for your help folks!

---

### **EDIT:**

In order to classify and treat my data correctly I would like to have a database for each pair stated in the Array. Obviously, I could re-write my app so that it is not needed and have one database with many collections and a key for the pairs inside each document but the data would just become messier.

Thanks @Alistair_Nelson for precising this part wasn't clear :)

Comment: Initializing a `MongoClient` keeps a connection pool, so you only really need to connect once and re-use the returned object throughout your app. See [the docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connection-pooling)

Comment: Hey @Svenskunganka! I read through the docs and it seems that it would help me: `// Reuse database object in request handlers` but I'm looking to create a new DB per iteration of my loop (array2) not re-use only one...
wouldn't your solution do just that: Create one DB and then recall that same DB ?

Comment: But *why* do you *need* to create a new connection for each loop? Why not just use the connection pool that `MongoClient` already keeps for you?

Comment: I don't need it, you're right. It's just that I'm not highly familiar with all this ... In the docs they use: `MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/integration_test"...` wouldn't this mean that I get connected to the "integration_test" database, reusing this only DB afterwards?

Comment: I think it would help if you were to explain what it is you are trying to do. it is not obvious why you would be wanting to create a new database for each iteration of your loops.

Comment: Done! as I put it above: In order to classify and treat my data correctly I would like to have a database for each pair stated in the Array. Obviously, I could re-write my app so that it is not needed and have one database with many collections and a key for the pairs inside each document but the data would just become messier.